# How to make a graph that dynamically loads from a object

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function deseneazaGrafic(valori) {
            var h = canvas.height;
            var w = canvas.width / valori.length;

            context.fillStyle = "#DEDEDE";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.strokeStyle = "black    ";
            context.lineWidth = 2;


            var f = canvas.height * 0.9 / Math.max.apply(Math, valori);

            for (var i = 0; i < valori.length; i++) {

                context.beginPath();
                context.rect((i + 0.1) * w, h - valori[i] * f, 0.8 * w, valori[i] * f);
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }



        $("#btnGrafic").click(function () {

            deseneazaGrafic(eval("[" + $("#valori").val() + "]"));

        });




        $("#scrie").click(function(){



        });
});
```

This is my java script. This makes a graph from some written values. How can i change the "valori" to be jsonObject.values?Thanks a lot

Comment: What does `$("#valori").val()` return?

Comment: There's a "textbox" on the html where you can enter the values : like "1,2,3,4," and the graph loads with 4 columns

Comment: <input id="valori" type="text" value="12, 13, 3, 2, 1, 10, 7, 18">

Comment: From where and how will you be pulling the JSON data?

Comment: It's a local json file. var jsonObject = { 
"id":"4000",
"name":"20"
} -> this is my json file. It doesn't matter if i have a json or not, all what i want to do is to draw a graph and the values of X and Y to get from a Var

Comment: Assuming `jsonObject` is a variable in your script and that the values are stored as an array in `jsonObject.values`, you should be able to just pass it to `deseneazaGrafic` like so: `deseneazaGrafic(jsonObject.values)`

Comment: That of course assumes the format `var jsonObject = { "values": [1, 3, 2, 7] }` for example.

Comment: And the  function deseneazaGrafic(valori) still remains the same?

Comment: Yes.  `deseneazaGrafic` accepts a simple javascript array which you can extract from a decoded JSON string.

Comment: Good, it worked ! I want to make a television rating, telespectators and so on... so, i need multiple values, how can i select some of them from the json file?

Comment: Unfortunately, that goes beyond the scope of the original question.  I suggest looking into documentation of JSON format and trying out a few things.  You will probably have to use an object instead of an array which will require a little reworking of your code, but if you get stuck on a part, feel free to ask as many questions on here as you need to.  Good examples of what you have already tried will help get you better answers.  Good luck!  I'll keep an eye out to see if you post any other questions and try to help where I can.

Answer (score 0):

As a formal answer (see question comments for details), the function `deseneazaGrafic` accepts a simple javascript array.  Right now it's `eval`ing (ew... bad) the value of a textarea (`#valori`).  You can use any javascript array.  When you get the values from your JSON file, just pass it to `deseneazaGrafic` as its parameter. For example:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(myJSONString);  // the JSON object contains an array called "values"

deseneazaGrafic(jsonObject.values);
```

That should render the graph just fine assuming the array is parsed correctly.

Comment: if i had 15 reputation, i vote your answer :) thanks a lot sir

Comment: Do you know how can i add below the graph some years? Like -> on 11/Nov there were 200 visitors (for every column). Thanks a lot !

Comment: @DonTzapone That's a tall order. :P  Canvas has to be my weakest point of knowledge when it comes to HTML5 but I'll give it a shot.  Here's the first attempt using static text: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/92xe77tu/.

Comment: @DonTzapone Here is a final version that now accounts for extra data in the array being passed to the graphing function: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/92xe77tu/2/

Comment: how can i put  jsonData = {
        values : [ .... in the json file? i cutted from there and pasted in json and the graph doesn't loads !

Comment: @DonTzapone The likely reason is that the parameters need to be encapsulated in quotes. Example: http://pastebin.com/AHd7Ezhq.  You can always validate JSON using services like [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com/). Edit: and the reason it needs to do that is because I just used a straight javascript object and skipped the parsing step for the demo.

Comment: I tried to encapsulate all parameters in quotes. i deleted jsonData={}.... from .js, and it still doesn't work

Comment: i need to put all the "values" json file into an object

Comment: Do you know how to make multiple Columns? Like -> to compare 2 values from json? To make 1 column behind to another.

Comment: The "values" field to be "BBC", with "date" & "val" and to make another "values" named "HBO" or something ... "HBO" has "date" & "val" aswell.

Comment: That functionality is going to take a lot of logic.  For starters, you'll want to structure your object to include something like `"val" : { "BBC" : 6, "HBO" : 9 }` instead of `"val" : 8` or whatever.  The calculation of where the bars should appear will have to be reworked entirely not to mention you now need room for a key and vertical labels.